# Doing pattern matching in SQL from java

Tags: java, string

I have a record in postgres table in a column as below

```
id   subtype 
1    type=[ep,hh]~region=[EU,NA]~version=[16,17]
```

When the subtype is passed as `type=[ep]~region=[NA]~version=[17]` 
I would like the id to be returned as 1. I can use the like clause with `%` and have a template, is there a better way than that.

I was planning to do

```
Select id 
from table_name 
where subtype like 'type=[%EP%]~region=[%NA%]~version=[%17%]'
```

while from sql it might work, when I construct the query string in Java, I get a format exception. Here is what I am doing

```
String SUB_TYPE_TEMPLATE ="Type=[%%s%]~Region=[%%s%]~Version=[%%s%]";
String subType = String.format(SUB_TYPE_TEMPLATE,type,region,version);
```

Also if the input is type=[hh,ep]~region=[NA,EU]~version=[16,17] the condition should still match..

Answer (score 0):

The `%` has a special meaning in a format-string, so you have to escape it:

```
String SUB_TYPE_TEMPLATE = "Type=[%%%s%%]~Region=[%%%s%%]~Version=[%%%s%%]";
String subType = String.format(SUB_TYPE_TEMPLATE, type, region, version);
```

Comment: Thanks, i am escaping,  Also if the input is type=[hh,ep]~region=[NA,EU]~version=[16,17] the condition should still match.. how do i achieve that..